# Django REST framework prefetch not working on model with multiple foreign keys to the same target

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, prefetch, django-prefetch-related

I'm writing an endpoint to fetch data from the "Term" model in Django REST framework and I'm trying to reduce queries by prefetching data. Specifically there is a model "TermRelation", that saves vector relation scores between individual terms that I would like to prefetch data from. Simplified, the models look as follows:

```
models.py

class Term(models.Model):
    term = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_('Term'), null=True, db_index=True)

class TermRelation(models.Model):
    src_term = models.ForeignKey(Term, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('Source term'),
                                    related_name='src_term_relation')
    trg_term = models.ForeignKey(Term, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('Target term'),
                                    related_name='trg_term_relation')
    vector_sim = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True, default=0.0, verbose_name=_('Vector similarity'), help_text=_('Cosine vector similarity.'))
```

And here's the simplified view:

```
views.py

class TermsList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Term.objects.prefetch_related(
            'src_term_relation',
            'trg_term_relation',
            'note_set',
            'usage_set'
        ).all()
        return queryset
```

There are other models related to term such as "Note" and "Usage" for which prefetch is working, only for relations it still makes a bunch of queries. I've included a screenshot of the [Django SQL debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yff0M.png) results, or rather the first few lines as this goes on for a while with the same queries. You can see that Django **does** run the prefetch operation, but then still makes the same queries as if it didn't happen.

What am I doing wrong? Could this be related to "TermRelation" having two ForeignKey fields pointing to the same model or REST framework not knowing how to resolve the related names?

**EDIT:**

Think I found something, the issue seems to lie elsewhere. In the serializer, there is a method field that counts the number of relations:

```
class TermSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    relations_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_relations_count(self, obj):
        rels = TermRelation.objects.filter(Q(src_term=obj) | Q(trg_term=obj))
        return len(rels)

    class Meta:
        model = Term
        fields = '__all__'
```

I'm assuming it runs a query over all TermRelations for each term that is returned by the serializer, ignoring the prefetched data. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Not related, but it's better to use TermRelation.objects.filter(Q(src_term=obj) | Q(trg_term=obj)).count() instead of doing len(), count request is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, may be it would solve additional queries problem

```
class TermSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    relations_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_relations_count(self, obj):
        return obj.src_term_relation.count() + obj.trg_term_relation.count()
```